# React native APK sin servidor

Tags: react-native

Hola amigos queria saber si se puede correr el apk que genere de react native, lo instalo en mi telefono pero me dice que necesita de correr react-native start osea que no es como un ejecutable como yo pense, necesito su ayuda :(

Answer (score 0):

El problema es que generas el apk en modo **debug**, el cual necesita que el servidor esté levantado.

Para correrla sin que el servidor esté levantado genera el apk en modo **release**.

```
react-native run-android --variant release
```